# Puzzles I made in Microsoft Paint

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Here are some puzzles I made out of boredom:

> [image: Blockquote]
>
> **Who are you trying to contact?**

> [image]
>
> **There are two answers**

> [image]

Comment: Maybe it's time for a hint?

Answer (score 1):

### Partial Solution

First puzzle (incomplete):

> The square is made of four sections which need to be rearranged; after doing so, they look like:

> [image]

> When flipped vertically, it appears to say `LM G`, but I don't know if that's the correct solve path.

Second puzzle (solved):

> The answer is ANYTIME / AMENITY, as those are the pangrammatic answers to the New York Times Spelling Bee puzzle on July 25, 2023.

Third puzzle (incomplete):

> It seems the arrow is pointing to the user avatar / profile link. On their profile, the following text is displayed:

> so the other day i was eating a bagel and then when i woke up there was the bagel and then what happened next was the sandwich i ate that but then you won’t believe this part i went to bed and woke up the next morning and i can’t believe this but i woke up and then i ate another bagel like can you believe that like what is going on so then i hopped in my bed and went to bed and then when i woke up i woke up the next morning bro what is going on i have to contact someone but what’s even crazier is that the bagel when i woke up woke up in the morning when i bageled the cream cheese like what’s going on? why did my dad never came back with the milk and why is the bagel in my sleep my sandwich my bed into the cream cheese this is just outlandish where is joe biden he’s probably not even bageling my sandwich in cream cheese

> The "where is joe biden" in the text confirms this text is relevant to this puzzle.

Comment: FYI, the last spoiler is not correct. look at the sequence at the top. And, your solving path on the first puzzle is correct.